# Inversion Puzzle

Tags: visual

[image]

You can describe your inversions however you like.  I think an ordered grid from the center (n,m) is easy to understand (doesn't matter where to start due to radial symmetry), or an image

Comment: Neat puzzle! Is there a reason why the black regions are not uniform? It's not important, but it makes the puzzle slightly harder to solve using an image editor because it breaks floodfilling.

Comment: Because I drew them in procreate.  Thats a good point I'll remember that next time I make something like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution is

> 2 moves to make the inversions - was very slow to make this horrible graphic!
>  [image]

Comment: Correct! Also works with most circles and sections

Comment: I would have drawn it quicker by making a fresh start with an 8 x 4 rectangular grid. I was able to floodfill the white areas with black but somehow not with black areas with white.

Comment: Black areas are shaded.  Will make it easier next time.  You can see the shading better here https://m.imgur.com/Sg5RLNi

Comment: My apologies to @PiIsNot3 because I inadvertently copied his final image, mistaking it for the one in the puzzle. Corrected.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** I found an even better

> **2 inversion** solution:
>  [image]
>
>  And of course, this is the optimal solution because you obviously can’t get to the end with only one inversion

**Original answer:** I can do it in

> **6 inversions**

by

> inverting a set of 4 non-adjacent big triangles (the ones that go BWBW or WBWB), then inverting the 2 black rings that result from that. (Will update with a visual later)

Comment: Correct! Not sure who got it first but both correct

Comment: @ArtemLugin this was first with the 6 solution, I was working on the graphic for my 2 solution when PilsNot3 announced he had found a 2 solution. However I didn't post anything until mine was ready.